# Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: &quot;&quot; LINE 5: where att_date between coalesce(''::date,'01-01-1990'::date)

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, sql-injection

Here i have a minor problem with my sql query. But realy i am unable to figure out what to do.
I have write the query too below so that you guys can understand how this error can be resolved.
Immediate help will surely be appreciated.

The type for  column "att_date" defined as "timestamp with time zone" in the postgres database.

Thanks

```
select (select emp_code ||' - '||first_name ||' '||last_name from person where person_id =  da.person_id) as emp, att_date, timein, timeout, totalhrs,
        totalothrs, isholiday, (select element_name from elements where element_id = da.element_id) as leavetype,daily_attendance_id
        from daily_attendance da
where att_date between coalesce('$prd_st'::date,'01-01-1990'::date) and coalesce('$prd_end'::date,'12-31-4712'::date)
and ad_client_id =  $_SESSION[clientid]
    order by 3;";
```

Comment: kindly let me know what should i do ..how should i modify the query  so that error can be removed.

Comment: What is `prd_st` and `$prd_end`, if there are variables/parameters, where did you declare them ?

Comment: Looks like `$prd_st` is empty.

Comment: prd_st and prd_end i have get from session and get them using below code.$prd_st = @$_GET['std'];
$prd_end = @$_GET['end'];

Comment: $prd_st = @$_GET['std'];
$prd_end = @$_GET['end'];

Answer (score 1):

### Immediate cause: Confusion between empty string `''` and `NULL`

`''` is not the same as `NULL`.

`coalesce(NULL, '01-01-1990'::date)` is `01-01-1990`. `coalesce('', '01-01-1990'::date)` is an error, and will emit exactly the error message you get:

```
regress=# SELECT coalesce('', '01-01-1990'::date);
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: ""
LINE 1: SELECT coalesce('', '01-01-1990'::date);
                        ^
```

when run standalone from `psql`.

If you want `NULL`, write `NULL`, not `''`.

### Root cause: bad coding practices

Read [the PHP manual on SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and http://bobby-tables.com/ then *go fix your code* to use [PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) or [`pg_query_params` with a parameters array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php). PHP programmers usually call this "prepared statements", though "parameterised queries" is more accurate.

Not only will this fix your problem, it'll get rid of the gaping security holes in your code.

*Never* interpolate strings into SQL. If someone tricks your app (say, with a direct POST, modified form, etc) into sending `');DROP TABLE daily_attendance;--` you'll be pretty annoyed.

Hint: If you pass the PHP `null` value to `pg_query_params` or a PDO parameter bind method, it'll be passed as the database `NULL`. So you don't need to special-case entering the `NULL` keyword when using bound parameters ("prepared statements").